# Variable stuck in a "for" powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, scope

I am have been trying to get out, the variable `$groupUsers` (array) that is stuck in inside a for. 
I have being researching about the scopes of the variables an I have found that a variable need to be global if I want it to be available in all the function.

I have tried putting the array outside the `foreach`, the if the for and even converting it to `$global:groupUsers` but it doesn't work.

```
        function get-localadmins{
          [cmdletbinding()]
         param( [string[]] $machineslist)


        #split computers list
        $separator = ","
        $option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
        $computerSplit = $machineslist.Split($separator, 20000 ,$option)

        #input credentials 
        $credential = Get-Credential kimo\admin0987

        ######## Create empty array to use in the for #####
        $groupUsers = @()

        foreach ($computer in $computerSplit)
        {

        $session = new-pssession -computername $computer -Credential $credential

        If ($? -eq $false )


                {
            $alert = "La conexion remota de ""PSSRemoting""no pude ser establecida con este equipo porfavor verifica WinRM has been updated to receive requests. WinRM service type changed successfully. WinRM service started. WinRM has been updated for remote management. WinRM firewall exception enabled. que la politica de este activada o corre el commando asdfjsfda para habilitar powershell remoto "
        } 
        else
        {


        new-pssession -computername $computer -Credential $credential
        $admingroup2 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
        $group = get-wmiobject win32_group -ComputerName localhost -Filter "LocalAccount=True AND SID='S-1-5-32-544'"
        $query = "GroupComponent = `"Win32_Group.Domain='$($group.domain)'`,Name='$($group.name)'`""
        $list = Get-WmiObject win32_groupuser -ComputerName localhost -Filter $query
        $admingroup = $list | select PartComponent # | % {$_.substring($_.lastindexof("Domain=") + 7).replace("`",Name=`"","\")}

        $clean = $admingroup

         for($i = 0; $i -lt $clean.length; $i += 1)
                    {
                        $string = $clean[$i] | Out-String


                        $domainPosition = $string.lastindexof('Domain=') + 7
                        $nextComma = $string.substring($domainPosition).indexOf(',')
                        $domain = $string.substring($domainPosition,$nextComma-1)

                        $namePosition = $string.lastindexof('Name="') + 6
                        $name = $string.substring($namePosition)


    #####this is the variable that I can get outside the for ######


                          $groupUsers += $domain + "\" + $name

                        Write-Host $groupUsers "inside for"
                    }

          Write-Host $groupUsers "outside for"
        }




        }



        }

############### I need to get the variable here ###################
        $groupUsers| ConvertTo-Html 


         Write-Host $groupUsers "out side the for-each "
        }

        $222 = get-localadmins localhost,machine1,machine2
```

Comment: Do your `Write-Host` calls work? Do they show the value of `$groupUsers` correctly?

Comment: yes the Write-Host $groupUsers "inside for" have the information that I need and it shows the admin users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the only problem you have here is that you aren't getting `$groupUsers` returned from the function. That's because you're never returning it!

`Write-Host` writes directly to the host application as a way of showing data without including it in the pipeline.

To return data, use `Write-Object` or just don't qualify it at all:

```
                      $groupUsers += $domain + "\" + $name

                    Write-Host $groupUsers "inside for"
                }

      Write-Host $groupUsers "outside for"
      $groupUsers # this will return it
    }
```

Then your `$222` variable will contain the value.

You don't need `$Global` scope here.

Comment: I dont wanna return the $groupUser variable. because the fuction receiver a list of computer as parameter . If a computer meet the requirements of the else, the execution will stop and will not process the list of machines. My idea is to create a object($groupUsers) with the processed data and then create a html report with $groupUsers |converto-html

Comment: @kimopryvt: What briantst said is the correct way to return `$groupUsers`. That is what your question is about. If you need help with something else, please open a new question.